# place table ontop of an image

Tags: c#, html, css, razor

I have a table that i want to place over an image the catch is that the tables content is dynamic so the image size would need to shrink or grow depending on the size of the table, what is the best way to achieve this.

This is the image: http://postimg.org/image/s2vjf4p3t/

And here is the html for my table

```
    <table id="menutable">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:100px;">Day</th>
                <th style="width:150px;">Meal</th>
                <th class="text-center">Normal</th>
                <th style="width:20px;"></th>
                <th class="text-center">No carb</th>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th style="width:240px;" class="text-center">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            Kiddies
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            Standard
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            Large
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </th>

                <th></th>

                <th style="width:240px;" class="text-center">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            Kiddies
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            Standard
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            Large
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

            @{


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)//foreach day in the week
    {

        string size = "";
        string type = "";
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:top; font-size:20px;">@Model.Menu[i].Day</td>

            <td>
                <b>@Model.Menu[i].NormalMeal</b>
                <br />
                <p>@Model.Menu[i].Description</p>
                <p><b>@Model.Menu[i].LowMeal</b></p>
            </td>

            @for (int p = 0; p < 2; p++) //for normal and nocarb
            {
                if (p == 0)
                {
                    type = "normal";
                }
                else
                {
                    type = "nocarb";
                }
                if (p == 1)
                {
                    <td></td>
                }
                <td class="text-center">

                    <div class="row">
                        @for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) //the sizes
                        {
                            if (j == 0)
                            {
                                size = "kid";
                            }
                            else if (j == 1)
                            {
                                size = "standard";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                size = "large";
                            }
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <select style="position:relative;top:0px; font-size:12px;" name="@(Model.Menu[i].Day.ToLower().ToString() + "_"+type+"_" + size)" @if (i <= disabledDays) { @disabled  }>
                                    <option> </option>
                                    @for (int k = 1; k <= 10; k++)
                                    {
                                        <option>@k</option>
                                    }
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        }

                    </div>
                </td>
            }


        </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6">
                        <hr />
                    </td>
                </tr>
    }
            }
        </tbody>

        <tfoot>

        </tfoot>

    </table>
```

Comment: This doesn't look like valid HTML to me... how is it possible to have C# in there?

Comment: @Jashaszun Looks like ASP.NET with Razor Syntax to me.

Comment: @GamerNebulae Interesting... I've never head about that before. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i ended up splitting the image into 3 parts namely top middle and bottom and for the body of the table for each row i added css background of the middle image and to sort out the position of the table to get it into the middle of my image i added an extra table cell to the beginning and end of the table and gave it a specific width so that it was no longer in the border of my image

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do here is put the table and the image in the same container.
Make the image absolute, so that the container's size is determined by the table, while the image should have 100% width and height too fill it out.

Your code should look something like this:

```html
  <div style="position:relative">
    <img src="" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%" />
    <table>
    ...
    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Ive tried what you suggested and now have this: http://postimg.org/image/vabjauert/   so tried positioning the table into the center of the image with some css adding some top and left to the table and get this: http://postimg.org/image/yo20i5l61/   
Any other suggestions you could mention?